# java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to myclass - gson

Tags: java, android, gson

I want to use `Gson` library but I get this error :

> java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to `UserHelper`

The `UserHelper` is my class helper:

```
String user_id="",pass="",show_other_profile="",status="",instagram_link="",
    facebook_link="",google_plus="",telegram_link="",website_link="",birthday="";
```

---

value of `str` variable :

```
[{"user_id":"27","pass":"c3992a14e2887f551119b8b72b08fe12","show_other_profile":"","status":"","instagram_link":"","facebook_link":"","google_plus":"","telegram_link":"","website_link":"","birthday":""}]
```

---

```
UserHelper h = new UserHelper();
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<UserHelper>>() {}.getType();
h = gson.fromJson(res, listType); // error line
```

---

**solved**

```
arr_users = gson.fromJson(res, listType);
h = arr_users.get(0);
```

Comment: You've explicitly asked to deserialize the JSON into a `List<UserHelper>`. Why do you expect  to get back a `UserHelper`?

Comment: you're right. solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams that `str` contains an array of `UserHelper` and you are trying to deserialize it as an `ArrayList<UserHelper>` which cannot be cast into a `UserHelper`

If you are certain the list always contain one single item, then you may replace the last line with:

```
h = gson.fromJson(res, listType).get(0);
```

Comment: .get(0) function undefined.

Comment: @S.M_Emamian this is strange since you are marking it solved with the exact same solution :)